# Is "Announceable" as a noun an Australianism?

Tags: business-language, australian-english, zero-derivation

I just heard of the word "Announceable" being as a noun. This word was announced as a Word of the Year candidate in [2011](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/news/view/article/57/) by the Macquarie Dictionary. An example from 2010, albeit using sneer quotes: [Less spin, more heart, PM Julia Gillard vows](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/national-affairs/less-spin-more-heart-pm-julia-gillard-vows/story-fn59niix-1225916804560)

> The Prime Minister has told her MPs at their first caucus meeting
>   since the election that Labor must renew its sense of purpose, and she
>   assured them that she would not be looking for an "announceable" for
>   the six o'clock news.

Doing an anonymous search of google.com (not google.com.au) and of Twitter mainly got hits from Australia and Australian twitterers. This sounds fairly plausible, because Australians love to mock the spin of our politicians ([The Hollowmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollowmen), [Utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(Australian_TV_series)) (known as Dreamland elsewhere)). But I'm not sure where to find confirmation.

Is "Announceable" as a noun an Australianism, more common in Australian English than British and American English?

Comment: I haven't heard "announceable" as a noun where I'm from (AmE), so it's plausible it's dialectical. I have heard the similar term "call an audible", which means "to change plans at the last minute", a metaphorical extension of the act, in American football, of the quarterback calling out (audibly) a play change to the rest of the team on the field, typically after he's assessed the opposing team's composition and formation and changed his plans accordingly (so typically at the last minute).

Comment: In the context used (especially given the "scare quotes"), nouning an adjective such as "announceable" is legitimate in informal text (and most newspaper usage would be considered informal).

Comment: Now I am wondering about *sneer quotes* as an alternative term for the more common *scare quotes.* I confess I rather like the term, as agreeing with my general dislike of the punctuation so described.

Comment: It appears to have some life in Canadian parliamentary slang.  See: http://www.parli.ca/gainsburger/  also, Google has more but also picks up some of the Australian references. https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=announceable&tbs=ctr:countryCA&cr=countryCA

Comment: I am vaguely recalling that I've heard "announceable" as marketer's jargon in the computer company I used to work for.  Prior to the announcement of a product they will circulate documents listing the "announceables" (features with strong selling points) the product contained.

Comment: Let us not forget that Julia Gillard gave us the new Australianism *hyperbole* -- pronounced *hyper-bowl*. 


  [1]: http://www.news.com.au/national/julia-gillards-genuine-mispronunciation-turns-hyperbole-into-hyperbowl/story-e6frfkvr-1226035582372

Comment: @HemiPoweredDrone - Isn't that how everyone pronounces it??

Comment: It was commonly used in the UK (London) where I worked in PR from 2011 - 2016.

Comment: I've never heard "announceable" in the U.S., but we do use the noun "deliverable" in some contexts. The words can often be used similarly (according to the examples I see below), so perhaps that is why "announceable" never caught on here.

Comment: The noun is in Wiktionary (2022), with the sole caveat 'informal'. // Sneer quotes? New and unusual usages are the way the language moves forward.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, "Announceable" did originate in Australian political satire, but as the quote shows it has moved into common usage here; that was a leading politician, offering a quote for mainstream media consumption, which was presented verbatim (assuming the audience already understood its meaning).

But it's a very useful word that surely has broader relevance (beyond Australia). It concisely describes a politician's desperate, continuous search for something (anything) to announce at their next planned media event (a "presser", "door stop", "high viz", etc). The content of the announcement is immaterial - they just want anything that is "able to be announced".

Answer (score 1):

There are very few usage instances in ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=announceable&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cannounceable%3B%2Cc0)*** of ***annouceable*** as a noun where it is used with inverted commas. It appears to be a local, but uncommon, usage of the adjective as a noun.

> - ***The "announceable" at the Vancouver 1997*** Leaders Meeting was the endorsement of the "Early Voluntary Sectoral Liberalization" (EVSL), aimed at accelerating trade liberalization in nine sectors.([What's in a Name?: Globalization, Regionalization, and Apec](https://books.google.it/books?id=Wzq2AAAAIAAJ&q=%22announceable%22&dq=%22announceable%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTibWcsYbMAhUoD5oKHay6ACM4ChDoAQgrMAI) )

and:

> - A meeting of the National Security Committee of the cabinet has, however, recently asked for a list of national-security-related things that could be announced weekly between now and the election.
> - How much scrutiny has gone ***into these "announceables"*** is unclear.
>   ([Financial Review](http://www.afr.com/opinion/columnists/laura-tingle/tony-abbott-determined-to-lead-the-whitlam-government-of-our-time-20150813-giy574))

- It is mentioned as a noun in Wiktionary referring to the  mispelling  [announcable](http://www.yourdictionary.com/announcable#rirm82CBLd60dZA9.97).

Comment: I suspect that the scare-quotes are because the writers realize how cringeworthy this coinage is.